# Can I increase torque and Rpm in a DC electric motor safely using outside magnet

Tags: design

I'm wondering as a layman what would happen if you place a magnet on the outside of a DC motor. This has been documented on YouTube using a small 12v motor. I'm wondering what would happen to a larger DC motor say 500w 24v Would it hurt the motor? I'm thinking of series wiring two of these motors to the back wheels of my sons go kart and trying the outside magnet.If it is safe. Can someone help me out here 
Concerned Dad

Comment: Note that if you increase RPM you decrease available torque, and vice versa. So there is no magical gain going on here.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the external magnet(s) on in a way that reinforces the motor's own magnets, you will boost the magnetic field which will boost the peak torque output of the motor.

If you place the external magnet on in a way that cancels out the motor's own magnets, you will weaken the field.

In DC motors, stronger magnetic fields will tend to generate more torque, all other things equal.  For low-speed applications, you can get more torque.  For a go kart, this is probably where you would be operating.

In truth, you are adding to the field, but significantly influencing the motor characteristics using an external magnet would take a very strong magnet since you are so far from the rotor.  Motors are designed with the rotor very close to the magnet b/c the magnetic force weakens as a function of distance squared.  You would be better off simply increasing the voltage to get more performance out.  Mind the motor temperature.

Comment: Thank you,so basically just because the rotor revolves faster in rpm because of well placed earth magnets doesn't mean the motor outputs more top end speed.yes.This is my understanding of flux to torque and EMF to Flux.is this a yes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.  The first is that motors have a [magnetic circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit), which is made of (probably-permanent) magnets and iron, and the magnetic flux flows within that circuit.  Usually the case forms part of the circuit, so putting magnets outside the motor will put them outside the magnetic circuit and have very little effect on the actual magnetic flux through the windings, which is what you care about.

If it's not a permanent-magnet motor (e.g. is series-wound or separately-excited) then you cannot add permanent magnets.

Secondly, assuming you modified the motor casing to insert your bigger newer magnets into the magnetic circuit and thereby increased the magnetic flux, the effect would be to increase the motor's torque by some factor and also to reduce the motor's speed by the same factor.  You would mostly just be changing the motor's Kv parameter (google it), and you could theoretically run a higher current without it demagnetising but it's likely to run into thermal problems long before that effect becomes relevant.

Note that torque is proportional to current and flux, but also back-EMF is proportional to flux, therefore the speed of the motor will be reduced.

You could increase the supply voltage to get back to the same speed, but you are still going to run into the motor's thermal limits, which are mostly set by the total volume of copper in the windings and how efficiently the windings can dissipate heat.  For a competently-designed motor, the power limit will be thermal, so you can't get more power by just cranking up the field.  Increasing the field just pushes the torque curve down to lower RPM.

In summary: don't bother with the external magnets.  It's basically a waste of time because you can't beat thermodynamics even if you are a motor-designing ninja.  1kW of DC motors on a go kart will move pretty quickly anyway as long as the gear ratio is appropriate, and if the motors are not powerful enough then you need to buy bigger motors

Comment: what youtube video?  Note that a motor has a torque/speed curve and that by increasing torque, you may increase its speed under some operating conditions.  There is still no free lunch, and that result does not necessarily apply to your situation because it depends entirely on the final gear ratio.